# How invite facebook friends and get their id from ios app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-invite

I develop ios app with chats (it's not game). I have a task to invite all fb friends(not only who using my app) to a defined chat in my app. So for do this I need get all friend list, choose friens, send them notification(post on wall or message) and save fb friiend's id to my server. What I should use for implemetation this all things?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invitable_friends_without_canvas

Answer (score 1):

Facebook iOS sdk has all the features you need. You can see the friend list of the user logged in using Facebook session, etc more info at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/sample-apps

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I need more concrete information in this question. I try to use Message Dialog but I can't get what the friend id was selected by user. Send Dialog don't allow send message or post on wall to concrete  friend.